# adding items to tableView in IOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

Can someone go help me figure out how to hookup the table view so that i can add items to the table view? I'm trying to make a news screen for this app and am having trouble adding data to it. I have the xib file all set up i just don't know how to hook it all up in xcode 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looked like you have not use UITableView class before.  I would suggest get one of the samples from Apple.  Here is the [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).